# How do you code Negative Binomial Distribution in R

Tags: statistics, negative-binomial

How do I code the following questions in R?

When a machine is improperly adjusted, it has probability 0.105 of producing a defective item. Each day, the machine is run until 3 defective items are produced. When this occurs, it is stopped and checked for adjustment.

1. What is the probability that an improperly adjusted machine will produce 6 or more items before being stopped?
2. What is the average number of items an improperly adjusted machine will produce before being stopped?

Comment: `pnbinom(q, size, prob, mu)` works in R as do the d/q/r types

Comment: what is mu in this question?

Comment: See the [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/NegBinomial.html) which says `mu  alternative parametrization via mean` and is going to be equal to `size * (1 - prob)  / prob ^2` so you can choose whether to use `prob` or `mu`.  In R's negative binomial distribution, `prob` is the probability of a success and `size` is the specified number of successes before the experiment is stopped; Wikipedia does it slightly differently